To prove with equations that the circle turns into an ellipse in perspective projection
I want to show that the equation of a circle in perspective projection turns into an ellipse, but only by creating the scene, I can use locus or show trace, which is not a convincing scene because it does not show exactly with equations.
(Perspective Drawing of Circle) I tried to make a setup using the equations in this article but it didn't happen
Can you help me with a setup where I can see the equations?
https://www.geogebra.org/classic/ecbfsyrs I tried, but I was not convinced because I could not see the inversion of the plane and the equations exactly.
